# How to use convolution operator in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convolution

```
  I = imread('13.jpg');
  Ir = I(:,:,1);
  Ig = I(:,:,2);
  Ib = I(:,:,3);

   %# Create the gaussian filter with hsize = [5 5] and sigma = 2
   G = fspecial('gaussian',[10 10],1);
  %# Filter it
  Ig = imfilter(I,G,'same');
  %# Display
  imshow(Ig);

  PSF = fspecial('gaussian',7,10);

  Irc = conv2(Ir,PSF,'same');
  Igc = conv2(Ig,PSF,'same');
  Ibc = conv2(Ib,PSF,'same');
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
       Warning: CONV2 on values of class UINT8 is obsolete.
       Use CONV2(DOUBLE(A),DOUBLE(B)) or
       CONV2(SINGLE(A),SINGLE(B)) instead. 
       In uint8.conv2 at 11
       In Gaussian_Filter_image at 19 
      Warning: CONV2 on values of class UINT8 is obsolete.
       Use CONV2(DOUBLE(A),DOUBLE(B)) or
       CONV2(SINGLE(A),SINGLE(B)) instead.
```

> ```
>     In uint8.conv2 at 11
>        In Gaussian_Filter_image at 20 
>        Undefined function 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'double'
>        and attributes 'full 3d real'.
> ```

```
      Error in uint8/conv2 (line 18)
       y = conv2(varargin{:});

       Error in Gaussian_Filter_image (line 20)
       Igc = conv2(Ig,PSF,'same');
```

Here I want to perform convolution of image and gaussian filter but I am unable to do that ?

I have even tried the modification after using

```
   Ir = double(:,:,1);
   Ig = double(:,:,2);
   Ib = double(:,:,3);
```

then also I am getting the same error?

Comment: It should be `Ir = double(I(:,:,1)); ...`, not `Ir = double(:,:,1); ...`

Comment: This is a _programming_ question (or debugging question) about MATLAB, not a question about signa processing, and should be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because image `I` is of class (data type) 'uint8', and the arguments to `conv2` must be of class 'single' or 'double', i. e. floating point. You can get rid of the error by converting `I` to double.  The best way to do that is to call `I = im2double(I)`, which will re-scale the pixel values to be between 0 and 1.

But looking at the big picture, you should not use `conv2` at all, and use `imfilter` instead, which does take 'uint8' images.  Look at the help for it.  By default it does correlation, but it can also do convolution.